# Totally unstructured data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, key-value-store

We currently have a solution were we are having more and more the need to store unstructured data of various kinds. For example clients have the ability to define their own workflows where they define what kind of data should be captured (of various types...some simple some complex). This data then needs to be stored and are then displayed on a web application with a bit of functionality to modify the data.

Until now the workflows have been defined internally and therefore a MS SQL database was designed to cater for these specific workflows and their data. However now that clients have the ability to define workflows we need to relax the structure of our db. At first I thought that a key value table in ms sql might be a good idea but obviously I lose the typeness of the data being capture and then need to deserialize all the data in website (MVC.NET).  I am also considering something like raven db but are not sure if this would be a good fit?

So my question  is thus what would be the best way to store this unstructured data bearing in mind users must be able to search and edit/display this data as well?

Comment: Perhaps a table for each user, with their name or employee ID as the key. The table would detail each project by date, name and authorisation, and then have a large string field detailing their project map? With perhaps some sort of workflow diagram in an image, hosted on the same server?

Comment: @Wolfish I do not know the users in advance and I also want to be able to add data afterwards. So kind of like a relational database but without the fixed structure if that even makes sense.

Comment: I vote for http://www.mongodb.org/, it has support for fulltext search, unstructured data, etc. Many big companies use it today, http://www.mongodb.org/about/production-deployments/.

Comment: @Murdock Aye, make a simple winform that requires the user to register their name and employee number, and subsequently attach any projects via their number. Something like an sproc that creates a new table, with their details. I dunno if I'm getting my point across, sorry

Comment: @Murdock Also, mongo is fairly decent. If you already have a license for MS-SQL though, I'd consider using that first.

Comment: @ThQ.. thanks for pointing `mongodb` out.. Somebody pointed out that in case similar to what @Murdock has, I should use an `unstructured SQL` database. I did quite a bit of research.. is there really anything like that `SQL` by its definition needs to have a structure for it work? Can `NoSQL` databases be read using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

How about combining 2 types of databases. Use a NO-SQL database for your unstructured data and the relational MS SQL database to save the references of your data for each workflow to retrieve them later on?

The data type will always be a problem and you always have to de-serialize it. Searching can be done by using the string representation of each value in your workflow and combining them in a searchable field in your MS SQL row.